# Создание C# обертки для библиотеки распознавания речи “Воск”

Tags: распознавание-речи, kaldi

Моя система: Linux Mint 19 Tara 64-битная.
Пробую сделать C# обёртку для VOSK как написано тут https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install
Получаю подобные ошибки: "g++: error /home/user/kaldi/kaldi/src/online2/kaldi-onlie2.a: No such file or directory".
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не правильно.

[image: Ошибки при компиляции]

Comment: Как я вижу на картинке - не хватает библиотек. корее всего, Вы что пропустили из инструкции по созданию обёртки. Например, какой нибудь билд.
Еще: там на сайте врое есть запуск через докер, может, это попроще будет?

Comment: я на картинку посмотрел еще раз, там нет полного лога - что вы делали. Вот make вижу, а make install, котрый обычно и ставит библиотеки куда надо - не вижу

Answer (score 0):

Kaldi надо сначала собрать, как указано в [инструкции](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install#compilation-from-source):

```
git clone -b lookahead --single-branch https://github.com/alphacep/kaldi
cd kaldi/tools
make
```

установить все зависимости и запустить make ещё раз, пока не соберётся

```
extras/install_openblas.sh
cd ../src
./configure --mathlib=OPENBLAS --shared --use-cuda=no
make -j 10
```

Все .a файлы должны после этого присутствовать